# One specific value not appearing for Choropleth

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis, choropleth

I am sorry if this has been asked before, but I could not find a solution for it and I am fairly new to the coding world., I am trying to plot a choropleth map for a school project. I have data which just has ZIP codes and the sales which I have to use. I found a set of data online (from:
https://simplemaps.com/data/us-zips) which has ZIP code and FIP code as well. I merged the two files based on the ZIP code and use the new file for the choropleth code. Unfortunately, Fayette (ZIP code: 35555 and FIP code: 1057) never appears on the map. I can see the other points, but just not fayette.
Below is my complete code

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
```

I got the geojson file from this link:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties- 
fips.json') as response:
counties = json.load(response)

df = pd.read_excel('new_data.xlsx') # this is the company's data 
df1 = pd.read_csv('uszips.csv')
```

My excel files look like this:

[This is my database of the sales of a company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0P7O.png)
[This is the data i got online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzgz4.png)

```
df_new = (pd.merge(df, df1, how = 'inner', left_on = 'ZIP', right_on = 'zip'))
df_new.drop_duplicates(subset ="ZIP",keep = 'first' , inplace = True) 

fig = px.choropleth(df_greater, locations = 'county_fips', scope= 'usa' , geojson= counties, 
hover_data= ['Sales 2017 - 2021'] ,hover_name= 'Customer City' , color= 'Scaled log sales')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Without your data, it is difficult to determine the cause. Can you provide sample data, please refer to this as this is a close [example](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-map-using-geojson) using user data with FIPS data.

Comment: Hi, r-beginners, thank you for your reply. I did already find the solution for the problem. The choropleth code accepts the FIPS code as a 5 digit number. Fayette (one of many) has a 4 digit FIP code which was the problem. I simply added a zero at the start to all the FIPS which had 4 digits so that they appear on the map. It is fixed now, thank you!